# hello when i'm installing magento this error appeared what shall i do?

Tags: magento2

[image]

I got this **error** when trying to **install magento** what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

> Deployment config file config.php is not writable.

set the write permission for app/etc/config.php

Here is easy [guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html) how to handle possible installation errors